# Bluetooth Concurrent connection

Tags: sensor, bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

I have multiple sensors that sends data via bluetooth to my laptop.  At present, I can only connect one bluetooth sensor with the bluetooth of my laptop. It needs pairing, and then connects. So if I want to get the data from the other sensor, I need to disconnect the first sensor, then connect the second sensor. and so on.

1- Right now I do this connection/disconnection manually. How do I automate it?
2- Can we not have concurrent connections in case of Bluetooth?

Similar questions have been asked such as [Microcontroller Bluetooth Multiple Connection Support](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/224968/microcontroller-bluetooth-multiple-connection-support) and [Multiple connection of bluetooth to android](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/381096/multiple-connection-of-bluetooth-to-android?rq=1)
But as you there is no clear answer.

Thank you very much in advance for your answer.

**Edit**

The central device is the laptop since it is receiving data from many similar sensors and will display on the GUI.

Answer (score 3):

> 2- Can we not have concurrent connections in case of Bluetooth?

Yes concurrent connections are possible, but not every BT/BLE chip supports this. You will need to check the reference manual of the BT/BLE chip of the central device to see whether your particular chip supports this. You did not state whether your laptop is the central or peripheral device in your scenario; the central is the device which initiates the connection.

> 1- Right now I do this connection/disconnection manually. How do I automate it?

Which part of the procedure do you mean? On the microcontroller: write firmware to do it. On your laptop: write software to do it. For more specific advice you will need to provide more details. Like whether you are using BT Classic or Low Energy, whether your laptop is the central device in this scenario, what bluetooth-chips your devices are using, which operating system is running on your laptop,....